# ¿Por qué se edita un array fuera de una función?

Tags: javascript

Este es el código:

```
  var codigos="1,2,3,5,9,7,11,25,96";
  var arraycodigos=codigos.split(",");
  console.log(arraycodigos); // [1,2,3,5,9,7,11,25,96]
  eliminar_arrayCodigos(arraycodigos,3);
  console.log(arraycodigos); // [1,2,3,9,7,11,25,96]

  function eliminar_arrayCodigos(arr,ind){
    arr.splice(ind,1);
  }
```

Mi pregunta es, por qué luego de ejecutar la función cambia la variable `arraycodigos` si en la función no hay `return`? No debería cambiar solo si en la función pongo `return arr`, y llamo a la función poniendo `arraycodigos=eliminar_arrayCodigos(arraycodigos,3);`????

Pasa lo mismo si uso `arr.push();` pero si hago esto, no cambia:

```
  console.log(arraycodigos); // [1,2,3,5,9,7,11,25,96]
  eliminar_arrayCodigos(arraycodigos,3);
  console.log(arraycodigos); // [1,2,3,5,9,7,11,25,96]

  function eliminar_arrayCodigos(arr,ind){
    arr=[];
  }
```

Sé que splice y push modifican el original, pero el original dentro de la función sería `arr`, ya que debería ser una variable independiente a `arraycodigos`, y en caso no sea así entonces al poner `arr=[];` también debería modificarlo, pero no lo hace.

Answer (score 0):

El método `splice` cambia los contenidos de un array en su sitio. Al llamarlo estás efectivamente modificando el arreglo original. `push` también modifica el arreglo original.

La [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) del método splice lee:

> *El método splice() cambia el contenido de un array eliminando elementos existentes y/o agregando nuevos elementos.*

Si lo que buscas es crear un nuevo arreglo sin algunos elementos, puedes usar funciones como `filter`, que corre una función en cada uno de los elementos y añade solo los elementos para los cuales la función retorna `true`:

```
const idxToDelete = 5
const newArray = array.filter( (x, idx) => idx !== idxToDelete);
```

o puedes crear una copia del arreglo antes de modificarlo:

```
function eliminar_arrayCodigos(array,ind){
  return [...array].splice(ind, 1);
}
```

pd: para eliminar un elemento teniendo acceso a su índice, no es necesario hacer un bucle.

Comment: Sí se que tanto splice como push modifican el original, pero el original dentro de la función sería la variable "array" que debería ser como una variable independiente del arraycodigos ya que está dentro de una función, además al poner array=[] estoy declarando que se haga un array vacío, estoy editando el original, sin embargo en ese caso continúa normal el array.

Comment: Otro ejemplo:
```
let x = 5;
let y = 6;
console.log(x); // 5
suma(x,y);
function suma(a,b){
 a=a+b;
}
console.log(x); // 5
```
Siguiendo la lógica de lo que pasa con los arrays, el último console.log me debería dar 11, ya que dentro de la función lo estoy modificando. Perdón mi ignorancia pero no entiendo

Comment: la variable `array = []` no hace nada... además cuando llamas la función no la asignas a nada. En el segundo ejemplo, llamas la función pero `x` y `y` nunca se modifican, además la función no retorna un valor. Te recomiendo que busques cómo funcionan los valores de retorno en las funciones:
`let x = 5; let y = 6; console.log(x); // 5` 
`x = suma(x,y); function suma(a,b){ return a=a+b; } console.log(x); // 11 `